# How to subtract start time from stop time

Tags: java, datetime

I've the following two dates in a string format and would like to get the elapsed time for those.

```
Date elapsed = new Date(
               new SimpleDateFormat().parse("10/17/2014, 2:19:22 PM").getTime()
               - new SimpleDateFormat().parse("10/17/2014, 2:19:32 PM").getTime());
System.out.println("Elapsed Time: " + elapsed);
```

However, I get `...ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/17/2014, 2:19:22 PM"` does anyone know why?

Note: here is how I got the date you see in parse block generated `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have to specify format in `SimpleDateFormat` constructor.
- Your `String` has *format* `dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a`
- Your logic of *substraction* is incorrect as it will give you the `long`  value difference between dates and you are creating date from that value which is *not valid*.For that you have to get exact difference from that long value.You have to divide *diff* with *(1000 * 60)* to get minutes, *(1000 * 60 * 60)* to get Seconds and *(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)* to get days.

  ```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a");
  long diff = sdf.parse("10/17/2014, 2:19:22 PM").getTime()
                          - sdf.parse("10/17/2014, 2:18:32 PM").getTime();
  System.out.println("Difference : " + (diff / (1000d * 60 )) +" Minutes");
  ```

*NOTE:* `1000d` is used to perform floating point arithmetic here.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I get ...ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/17/2014, 2:19:22 PM" does anyone know why?

Because you haven't told `SimpleDateFormat` what the format of the string will be. Use one of the constructor that [accepts a pattern string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-) so that it knows what to expect.

Comment: This is what I got `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("10/17/2014, 2:19:22").getTime()` and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Simple-Solution: Read the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`. `HH` means **two** digits in the hour. There is only one in your input. (It also expects a range from 0-23; I suspect you're dealing with 1-12.) You're probably looking for `h` (and just one of them).